# conditional logic and string operations in JAVA

Tags: java, conditional-statements

I am brand new and totally lost.  I am looking for a tutorial or resource that can explain to me how to do this:

> Output a message for each abbreviation that is expanded, then output the expanded line.

e.g.

```
Enter text: IDK how that happened. TTYL. 
You entered: IDK how that happened. TTYL.

Replaced "IDK" with "I don't know".
Replaced "TTYL" with "talk to you later".

Expanded: I don't know how that happened. talk to you later.
```

I know how to do the `userText.replace` part to change the `IDK` to `I don't know`, but I don't know how to set it up to search the string for `IDK`

Comment: Why would you need to search yourself? `replace` already searches and replaces for you....

Comment: I would suggest looking at HashMap<String, String> for that: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: not sure, as I said, no idea what I'm doing, but I know I'm supposed to use conditional formatting and idk how to do that

Comment: I don't think we've covered that yet Alexey, but I will look there

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.indexOf()` to find the first instance of a given string:

```
String enteredText = "IDK how that happened. TTYL.";
int pos = enteredText.indexOf("IDK");    // pos now contains 0
pos = enteredText.indexOf("TTYL");    // pos now contains 23
```

If `indexOf()` can't find the string, it returns -1.

Once you know that a value has been found ( by testing that `pos != -1)`, perform your replacement and output your message.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.indexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)) checking to see if each abbreviation exists in the input string and [`replaceAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to modify the string if it does:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter text: ");
    String text = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("You entered: " + text); 
    if(text.indexOf("IDK") != -1) {
      System.out.println("Replaced \"IDK\" with \"I don't know\""); 
      text = text.replaceAll("IDK", "I don't know");
    }
    if(text.indexOf("TTYL") != -1) {
      System.out.println("Replaced \"TTYL\" with \"talk to you later\""); 
      text = text.replaceAll("TTYL", "talk to you later");
    }
    System.out.println("Expanded: " + text);
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Enter text:  IDK how that happened. TTYL.
You entered: IDK how that happened. TTYL.
Replaced "IDK" with "I don't know"
Replaced "TTYL" with "talk to you later"
Expanded: I don't know how that happened. talk to you later.
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FRGb/0)

*Note: This above implementation does not deal with any irregular capitalization of input for that issue I suggest you look into [`toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()) or to [`toUppperCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase()).*